# How to use dataLoader in strawberry(Fast API, Sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, graphql, fastapi, strawberry-graphql

I have these three model. One user have multiple roles.I am stuck for get roles of user.
How can I get the user with roles using strawberry dataloader?

```
    class UserRole(Base):
        __tablename__ = "user_roles"
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
        user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
        role = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("roles.id"))
        created_at = Column(DateTime(), server_default=func.now())
        updated_at = Column(DateTime(), nullable=True)
    
    
    class Role(Base):
        __tablename__ = "roles"
    
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
        name = Column(String(255), unique=True, index=True, default="patient")
        description = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
        created_at = Column(DateTime(), server_default=func.now())
        updated_at = Column(DateTime(), nullable=True)
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return f"{self.name}"
    
    
    class User(Base):
        __tablename__ = "users"
    
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
        first_name = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
        last_name = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
        email = Column(String(255), unique=True, index=True)
        roles = relationship(
            "Role",
            secondary="user_roles",
            backref=backref("users", lazy="dynamic"),
        )
        created_at = Column(DateTime(), server_default=func.now())
        updated_at = Column(DateTime(), nullable=True)
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return f"{self.email}"
```

Now I am using this tutorial https://strawberry.rocks/docs/guides/dataloaders